# Tuple vs Class in Java

Tags: java, tuples

Are there any advantages of using Tuples instead of creating a new class in Java?
I've seen something like this a few times
`return Pair.of (username, password);`. And I've always wondered what kind of advantages it has in relation to something like this `return new Credentials (username, password)`.

Comment: I use tuples as internal data structures within classes but never as part of a public interface for a component. The reason I use tuples is that it is tedious to create classes for every single instance where a fixed number of fields are required, whereas tuples make it easy to encapsulate the fields of importance. The reason I do not use them in public interfaces is that although tuples preserve type information, semantic information is lost. Some languages have support for named tuple elements, where it may be possible to use them in public interfaces as well.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have a (first class) notion of tuples. Some projects and libraries introduce types like `Pair` or `Tuple2`/`Tuple3`/`Tuple4`/... to make up for it, but this is often considered poor style in Java.

By contrast returning a clearly-defined type like `Credentials` that provides not just structure but also type safety and meaningful getters for your data you make your code clearer, safer, and easier to work with. The [Auto/Value](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) project in particular makes it quick and painless to create [value-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type), making tuple-esque types all but unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

A Pair (Apache) is immutable, for one. You cannot change it’s values after creation. Many people do in fact choose to create their own class and add methods as necessary.

In general it’s considered better practise to make your own class. You can validate parameters and so on and have the ability to add additional functionality if the need arises.

Answer (score -1):

As dimo414 says, the `Pair` class is often encountered in 3rd party libs; it has two advantages:

- it makes defining a separate class for each key/value pairing unnecessary; so you don't need to define a `Credential` class. Of course, this should only be used to temporarily store data, not to be used within your implementation model.
- Even if you do have a `Credential` class already, usually `Pair` is immutable, while the `Credential` class may not be. That means that it may provide `setUsername()` and `setPassword()` methods which you don't always want; using a `Pair` class makes sure both key and value remain unchanged.

Comment: Since there isn't a single canonical `Pair` type saying "`Pair` is immutable" isn't very meaningful - there are probably just as many `Pair` implementations that are mutable as immutable. And if you create your own `Credentials` class you can make it immutable just as easily.

Comment: First argument, I see that has a problem, not a benefit. You would have to implement method like `login(Tuple value)`, but also `sendToEveryBody(Tuple value)`, you would never create a method to send a `Crendential` class to everybody, but you might find interesting to be able to send another type of information. You loose the safety of types

Comment: @dimo414 hence the "usually".

Comment: @AxelH You're right of course, you shouldn't use this to implement your actual domain; I've updated my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: It's still an odd assertion to make in the general case. If you happen to be using a mutable `Pair` you'd have been better off creating your own immutable class, but you need to inspect the `Pair` type to know whether the one you're using is immutable or not, rendering the general assertion fairly unhelpful. Put another way if I'm reviewing code that uses a `Pair` type I can't know a priori whether it's immutable or not just based on the name, so saying it's "usually" immutable isn't actionable.

Comment: But again, using the credential data, password should be stored in a specific manner to be cleaned from the memory as soon as possible. But an immutable instance (like Apache Pair) would give you trouble with that because a correct immutable instance would not let you erase a password from memory (usually using an array, it would return a copy).

Comment: @dimo414 You asked for the kind of advantages you can expect from using a `Pair` class; I answered that question. The ubiquitous Apache Commons Pair is immutable, so there goes. If you use a different `Pair` implementation, you have to be aware whether it's mutable, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: I'm not the OP, I didn't ask for anything.... If you want to tweak your answer to say "the Apache Common's `Pair` type is immutable" that would be reasonable, but it's confusing/misleading to claim immutability is an advantage of the general notion of a pair-like type.

Comment: @dimo414 sorry, saw your name in your answer and got confused. I do find my answer general enough.